# How to pass dataset column value to a function while using spark filter with scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bloom-filter

I have an action array which consists of user id and action type

```
+-------+-------+
|user_id|   type|
+-------+-------+
|     11| SEARCH|
+-------+-------+
|     11| DETAIL|
+-------+-------+
|     12| SEARCH|
+-------+-------+
```

I want to filter actions that belongs to the users who have at least one search action.

So I created a bloom filter with user ids who has SEARCH action.

Then I tried to filter all actions depending on bloom filter's user status

```
val df = spark.read...
val searchers = df.filter($"type" === "SEARCH").select("user_id").distinct.as[String].collect
val bloomFilter = BloomFilter.create(100)
searchers.foreach(bloomFilter.putString(_))
df.filter(bloomFilter.mightContainString($"user_id"))
```

But the code gives an exception

```
type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
required: String
```

Please let me know how can I pass column value to the BloomFilter.mightContainString method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
val sparkSession = ???
val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext

val bloomFilter = BloomFilter.create(100)

val df = ???

val searchers = df.filter($"type" === "SEARCH").select("user_id").distinct.as[String].collect
```

At this point, i'll mention the fact that `collect` is not a good idea. Next you can do something like.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val bbFilter = sc.broadcast(bloomFilter)

val filterUDF = udf((s: String) => bbFilter.value.mightContainString(s))

df.filter(filterUDF($"user_id"))
```

You can remove the broadcasting if the bloomFilter instance is serializable.

Hope this helps, Cheers.

Comment: not really sure why this was downvoted. comments will be help improve the quality of answers.

Comment: Thansk @Chitral, it works. Any comment on why I need a wrapper udf function instead of calling mightContainString directly?

Comment: Yes, spark sql DSL like filter, select, groupBy,  where etc, take in `Column` objects, that is why the UDF wrapper is required. Do upvote it if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Create filter:

```
val expectedNumItems: Long = ???
val fpp: Double = ???
val f = df.stat.bloomFilter("user_id", expectedNumItems, fpp)
```

Use `udf` for filtering:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val mightContain = udf((s: String) => f.mightContain(s))
df.filter(mightContain($"user_id"))
```

If your current Bloom filter implementation is serializable you should be able to use it the same way, but if data is large enough to justify Bloom filter, you should avoid collecting.